# Python, Django | Реализация тегов(фильтров) к постам. Many-to-Many

Tags: python, mysql, django, база-данных

Стоит задача, сделать систему тегов на сайте, дабы в будущем по этим тегам фильтровать контент. Но не могу разобраться как это правильно сделать. Единственная мысль которая приходит в голову - создать таблицу со столбцами "category" и 'tag', пример на скриншоте: [image: 1]

Но используя такой способ - нормализация пострадает, ведь в таблице будет много повторяющихся категорий. Можете подсказать, как это оптимизировать, используя только одну модель(model приложения в Джанго)?

Мне нужен примерно такой результат:

[image]

Вот мой код:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю ты хочешь тег привязать к категории? Лучше сразу к товару используя many to many. И тогда каждый товар будет иметь много тегов, тег "фрукты" - привязан к банану (товару). Но также банан привязан и к тегу c "c африки".

У тебя есть модель Товара, который в свою очередь связан с Категорией и Тегом.
И уже в админке будешь привязывать теги, и выводить их красиво потом в html шаблон как на твоей картинке.

```
class Category(models.Model):
      """Класс модели категорий"""
   name = models.CharField("Название", max_length=100)
   slug = models.SlugField("url", max_length=100)
   description = models.TextField("Описание", max_length=1000, default="")

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Категория"
    verbose_name_plural = "Категории"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
      """Класс модели тегов"""
    name = models.CharField("Тег", max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField("url", max_length=100, unique=True)
    published = models.BooleanField("Отображать?", default=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Тег"
    verbose_name_plural = "Теги"

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
       """Класс модели товара"""
    title = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField("url", max_length=100, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
    Category,
    verbose_name="Категория",
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True
)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag,blank=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Товар"
    verbose_name_plural = "Товары"

def __str__(self):
    return "{}".format(self.title)
```